# Play Framework: Page cannot be resolved

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

im trying to use this method for routing in the controller class

```
public static Result show(String page) {
String content = **Page**.getContentOf(page);
response().setContentType("text/html");
return ok(content);
}
```

but im getting an import error ,Page cannot be resolved i tried each import and  got error

which api i need to import??

im using this link as referance

[JavaRouting](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaRouting)

Comment: Why do you tag your question with 2.0 **AND** 1.x version while it's impossible combination???

Comment: Where is your `Page` class located?

Comment: package controllers;
public class Application extends Controller

Comment: but where is your `Page` controller (or maybe it's a model???)

Answer (score 4):

I just accidentaly discovered, that you just copied a [part of the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaRouting), right ? :)

This is a sample, **hypothetical** case usage of some method `getContntentOf(String page)` from some class `Page` but  it **doesn't** exist by default in Play. You can simplify that sample (for learning purposes) to:

```
public static Result show(String page) {
    return ok(page);
}
```

or, better just put your real logic there.

Comment: This was driving me nuts until I read your post.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Same as Michael. Drived me nuts.